# question about convert and extract month from datetime in python

Tags: python, datetime, split, apply

I was tring to extract month from a date column that is in string format as below

| release date |
| --- |
| 2009-2-10 |
| 2010-3-12 |
| 2021-4-12 |

the method I used:

```
def year(x):
  if x != np.nan:
    return str(x).split('-')[1]
  else:
    return None

df['month'] = pd.to_datetime(df['release_date'], errors = 'coerce').apply(year)
```

the str(x).split('-')[1] is expected to return the '2', '3', '4'

however, the error rised as such

`list index out of range` for `str(x).split('-')[1]`

but `str(x).split('-')[0]` worked perfectly.

I am not sure where did I do wrong in the code.
if someone could help me with it, I would really appricate it.

Comment: IIUC the column `release_date` contains strings or `NaN`? If so, why do you use `pd.to_datetime` and then cast the datetimes back to string? You could try `df['month'] = df['release_date'].str.split("-", expand=True)[1]` instead.

Comment: Thank you.     it is object data type, I am trying to convert it to datetime.

Comment: I guess its dtype is object because it has `NaN`'s in it? But again, why convert to datetime when you afterwards convert it back to string, in the `year` function?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `.dt` accessor to extract the month directly from the datetime object like:

```
df['month'] = pd.to_datetime(df['release_date'], errors='coerce').dt.month
```

Comment: yeah I know, I can also use lambda x: x.strftime('%Y'). I didn't use them because I just want to get more familiar with writing lambda function by converting lambda function to user defined functions and vice versa.